# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 354

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to save a post in wordpress, I get this message :

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in
>   wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 354

Line 354 in my theme:

```html
if ( ! empty( $_term ) ) {
  $clean_terms[] = intval( $_term[0] ); //Line : 354 
} else {
  // No existing term was found, so pass the string. A new term will be created.
  $clean_terms[] = $term;
}
```

This is the **function.php** of the my theme:

```html
<?php

require_once 'inc/functions-nav-menu.php';
require_once 'inc/functions-comments.php';
require_once 'inc/functions-custom-header.php';
require_once 'inc/functions-meta.php';
require_once 'inc/functions-sidebar.php';
require_once 'inc/functions-product.php';


/**
 * Load theme domain name to enable language support.
 */
load_theme_textdomain( 'smr', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

/**
 * Set post type to main query on home page, because of we are displaying products on front page
 *  * We use is_front_page() instead of is_home() condition because of if user made choice to
 *  * display page on frontend and selected two equal pages both in "Posts page" and "Front page"
 *  * select boxes - we will see list of products like list of pages.
 *  *
 *  * See difference between this conditional for more info.
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'smr-product' ) );

    return $query;
});

/**
 * Add editor styles to admin area
 * By default editor-style.css is loaded. Depending on "style_schema" option
 * we load corresponding stylesheets.
 *
 * Add theme supports
 *  * Thumbnails
 * Remove page supports
 *  * Comments
 */
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_editor_style();

    /* load editor-style css file in order to used style schema */
    $option = get_option( 'smr_theme_options' );
    switch ( $option['style_schema'] ) {
        case 'red': {
            add_editor_style('editor-style-red.css');
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Add theme supports thumbnails for post */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    /* Remove comments support for pages */
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );
});

/**
 * Retrieve protected post password form content.
 *
 * @return string HTML content for password form for password protected post.
 */
add_filter( 'the_password_form', function() {
    $post = get_post();
    $label = 'pwbox-' . ( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    return sprintf(
        '<form action="%s" method="post" class="post-password-protected">
         <p>%s</p>
         <input name="post_password" id="%s" type="password" placeholder="Type password here..." size="20" />
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="%s" />
         </form>',
        esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ),
        __( 'This post is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:', 'smr' ),
        $label,
        esc_attr__( 'Submit', 'smr' )
    );
});

/**
 * Registering new section on admin theme customization page to make ability to admin to switch theme styles.
 *
 * We have two style schemas: 'silver' and 'red'. 'silver' is used by default.
 * Admin chose of used schema is saved in option[smr_theme_options][style_schema].
 */
add_action( 'customize_register', function( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'smr_color_scheme', array(
        'title'    => __( 'Color Scheme', 'smr' ),
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'smr_theme_options[style_schema]', array(
        'default'        => 'silver',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'option',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'example_select_box', array(
        'settings'  => 'smr_theme_options[style_schema]',
        'label'     => __( 'Select Style Schema:', 'smr' ),
        'section'   => 'smr_color_scheme',
        'type'      => 'select',
        'choices'   => smr_theme_options_schema_style_get_allowed()
    ));
});

/**
 * Enqueues scripts and styles for front-end.
 *
 * Theme has choose style schema option, admin can choose it from theme customize menu.
 * In order to that choose, we load needed css file.
 *
 * @see action to hook "customize_register" below for more info about alowed switched styles.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    /* Stylesheet */
    global $wp_styles;
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-bootstrap-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/form.css' );

    /* load css file if needs (if theme style is not default) */
    $option = get_option( 'smr_theme_options' );
    if ( in_array( $option['style_schema'], array_keys( smr_theme_options_schema_style_get_allowed() ) ) &&
        file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/css/style-' . $option['style_schema'] . '.css' ) )
            wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-style-' . $option['style_schema'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style-' . $option['style_schema'] . '.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-style-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style-responsive.css' );

    /* Loads main stylesheet */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    /* Loads the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-ie-lt9', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie-lt9.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smr-stylesheet-ie7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie7.css' );
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'smr-stylesheet-ie', 'conditional', 'IE' );
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'smr-stylesheet-ie-lt9', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'smr-stylesheet-ie7', 'conditional', 'IE 7' );

    /* Javascript */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );

    /* Load script to renew social buttons data ( on front page, on product category page and on single product page ) */
    if ( is_home() || 'smr-product-category' === get_query_var('taxonomy') || ( is_single() && 'smr-product' === get_post_type() ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-smr-social-buttons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smr-social-buttons.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );

    /* we use jquery.isotope only on front page and product category page */
    if ( is_home() || 'smr-product-category' === get_query_var('taxonomy') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-jquery-isotope-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-smr-landing-page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smr-landing-page.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );
    }

    /* Load script for single product ( to hide/show "overview", "details" ) */
    if ( is_single() && 'smr-product' === get_post_type() )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-smr-product-single', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smr-product-single.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'smr-javascript-smr-common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smr-common.js', array(), FALSE, TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply', array(), FALSE, TRUE );
});

/**
 * Returns more button to use in except()
 */
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', function( $more ) {
    global $post;

//    return ! is_home()
//        ? '<div class="right read-more"><a class="btn" href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">Read more</a></div>'
//        : '&#32;<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">&#91;Read more...&#93;</a>';

    return '&#32;<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">&#91;Read more...&#93;</a>';
});

/**
 * Creates a nicely formatted and more specific title element text
 * for output in head of document, based on current view.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    /* Add the site name */
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    /* Add the site description for the home/front page */
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    /* Add a page number if necessary */
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'smr' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );

/**
 * Return allowed theme color styles array
 */
if ( ! function_exists('smr_theme_options_schema_style_get_allowed') ) {
    function smr_theme_options_schema_style_get_allowed() {
        return array(
            'silver'    => 'Silver',
            'red'       => 'Red'
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Displays navigation to next/previous pages when applicable.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'smr_content_pagination' ) ) {
    function smr_content_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;

        if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <nav class="nav-single">
                <span class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'smr' ) ); ?></span>
                <span class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'smr' ) ); ?></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </nav>
        <?php endif;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns default image url
 */
if ( ! function_exists('smr_get_default_image_url') ) {
    function smr_get_default_image_url( $type = 'smr-product' ) {
        $file_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder_' . $type . '.png';
        $file = get_template_directory() . '/images/placeholder_' . $type . '.png';

        return ( file_exists( $file ) ) ? $file_url : get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/placeholder_smr-product.png";
    }
}

/**
 * Display escaped title.
 * We add this function because wordpress doesn`t do it.
 * It means wordpress function 'the_title()'.
 *
 * @param $post - post id
 */
if ( ! function_exists('smr_the_title') ) {
    function smr_the_title( $post = 0 ) {
        echo esc_attr( get_the_title( $post ) );
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me find the bug?

Comment: Have you turned on WP_DEBUG to check for errors? https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: can you show what `$_term` contains, by doing `var_dump($_term)`?

Comment: this probably doesn't exist ```$_term[0]``` you can try ```if ( ! empty( $_term ) && isset(  $_term[0] ) ) ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..
Can you show me how I can make the changes?
I do not understand almost nothing of php ....